# JUnit report of testNG opening other project

Tags: selenium, junit, testng

I am executing automated tests with testNG(using Selenium in eclipse). When I click on the failed testcase in Junit editor (to update the failed testcase), it opens the class file for that testcase in some other project.(Not the one whose testcases are run using testNG.xml).I am executing the right testNG.xml belonging to the intended project.But the failure report in JUnit editor opens the testcase by same name in some other projects I used to work previously.

Comment: When you say Junit editor, which editor? Eclipse? Intellij?

Comment: I am working in Eclipse editor

Answer (score 0):

If you're running with TestNG in Eclipse, then it's probably a good idea to use the [TestNG plugin for Eclipse](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html).

Otherwise, closing the projects on which you're not working is usually a good idea. Less chance of confusion over names :-).